# The third conditional questions

Tags: conditionals

Today while speaking to a colleague of mine I said "Had you studied well, you would have cleared the exam ". I was rebuked for not using the third conditional correctly. I was told that the correct way to express this is " if you had studied well, you would have cleared the exam".

My question here is can I not use the third conditional without an "if". Even if i say had u studied well, it means the same thing.

Comment: What you said was fine. It's just another way of expressing that conditional. You can even tell your colleague that your way is slightly more up-register than his.

Comment: Certainly is. Even more up-register perhaps: "Were you to have studied well ..." (for the next occasion?). Or _even_ more so: "Would that you had studied well, for you would have cleared..." : - )

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your way is also correct.  You can invert the conditional clause and omit the *if* as you did.

Comment: Thanks Dusty. Is there a study material based on this for my reference. That way i will be able to share it with my teacher too.

Comment: @UtkarshaTiwari, Check this - http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv356.shtml

Comment: @UtkarshaTiwari A quick google didn't turn up much in the way of authoratative sources, but there's this: http://www.grammaring.com/conditionals-and-inversion and this from wikipedia (itself unsourced): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#Inversion_in_condition_clauses (i

Comment: *authoritative.  That's going to annoy me...

Comment: Dusty, don't allow it to annoy---copy, delete original, then repost edited comment. Alternatively, copy and paste into your answer to add support for an answer that is currently unsupported and might be construed as *mere* opinion.  :- )

Answer (score 0):

Your version is grammatically correct; it is in a more formal register than the structure in which you use the word *if*.