# A sentence from Intelligent Investor

Tags: meaning, grammar

Here is the sentence:

> In a more general sense, the later used phrase "reckless investors"
>       could be regarded as a laughable contradiction in terms—something like
>       "spendthrift misers"—were this misuse of language not so mischievous.

I understand what it tried to express, however, the last part "were this misuse of language not so mischievous" confused me a lot.  I don't know how it can fit in the sentence structure in English grammar.

Comment: *were  this misuse of language not so mischievous* is equivalent to *if this misuse of language were not so mischievous*. So you basically have an in-clause of a conditional statement added on.

Comment: The whole thing can be rewritten as *If this misuse of language **were**  not so mischievous,  in a more general sense, the later used phrase "reckless investors" **could** be regarded as a laughable contradiction in terms—something like  "spendthrift misers".*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The third conditional questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252124/the-third-conditional-questions)

Comment: @Clare - could you put that helpful comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

It should not be confusing: it is a particular (and more formal) construction for expressing a conditional clause  (which you could call '[conditional clause without if](https://www.englishgrammar.org/conditional-clauses/)').

> ..., *were* this misuse of language not so mischievous.

is equivalent to:

> ..., *if* this misuse of language *was* not so mischievous.

'Were' is an alternative form of 'was', in the **conditional**:

> ..., *if* this misuse of language *were* not so mischievous.

Usually, we pick up a conditional clause immediatly, as soon as we hear 'if'. In the other form, the giveaway is a verb in the conditional form:

> *If* you had studied more, you would have passed the exam.

is equivalent to:

> *Had* you studied more, you would have passed the exam.